# Using role="listitem" for elements that are not directly children of element with role="list"?

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, wcag, nvda

Basically for one of our accessibility requirements, we have to make explicit list markup using role="list" and role="listitem".

One issue I face is trying to do this on a search page with search results. Each search results, however, are wrapped in a 'row' div. 
so it's:

```
<div role="list">
    <div class="row">
        <a role="listitem"
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <a role="listitem"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <a role="listitem"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

^ what i want to do.

The screen reader, however, reads out that it's only 1/1 list item. Any way i acn fix this?

Comment: Why not just use `ul` and `li` here?

Answer (score 0):

Your `role="listitem"` should go on the "row" `<div>`.  The only children of `row="list"` that are allowed are listitems.

```
<div role="list">
    <div class="row" role="listitem">
        <a></a>
    </div>
    <div class="row" role="listitem">
        <a></a>
    </div>
    <div class="row" role="listitem">
        <a></a>
    </div>
</div>
```